# Overwriting imported routing params in YML

Tags: symfony, routes

In my Symfony 2.8 project, I have a routing file:

```
...
foo_common_routing:
    resource: "@FooBundle/Resources/config/routing/foo-common-routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    condition: "false == request.cookies.has('bar')"
...
```

And in `foo-common-routing.yml`:

```
route_foo:
    path: /foo
    defaults:
        _controller: FooBundle:Foo:foo

route_bar:
    path: /bar
    defaults:
        _controller: FooBundle:Foo:bar

route_baz:
    path: /baz
    defaults:
        _controller: FooBundle:Foo:baz
```

How to make `route_baz` ignoring condition `"false == request.cookies.has('bar')"` ?

So far I've tried:

```
(1)
route_baz:
    path: /baz
    defaults:
        _controller: FooBundle:Foo:baz
    condition: null

(2)
route_baz:
    path: /baz
    defaults:
        _controller: FooBundle:Foo:baz
    condition: ''
```

But none of above seem to be working.

Comment: have you tried a dummy condition? As example `'true == true'`? or more simple `'true'`?

Comment: @Matteo just tried things like `'true'`, `'false'`, `'true == true'`, `'true == false'`, `'1 == false'` and so on, nothing seems to change the behavior of parent condition

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it this way, what you need is a second routing file without the condition. Put your **route_baz** inside the second file.

```
...
foo_common_routing:
    resource: "@FooBundle/Resources/config/routing/foo-common-routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
    condition: "false == request.cookies.has('bar')"

another_foo_common_routing:
    resource: "@FooBundle/Resources/config/routing/another-foo-common-routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
...
```